# spring.datasource.initialize is deprecated

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a springboot application where I am trying to add following to `application.properties` file

> spring.datasource.initialize=false

When I add this I see a warning as below:

[image]

I tried finding out what's the new property that replaces this deprecated property but in vain.

Can anybody help on this!

Having a reference to a migration guide would be great.

Comment: Use `spring.datasource.initialization-mode'`

Comment: isn't initialization mode different from initialize?

Comment: if you don't want you can still you use `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never`

Comment: looks like lots of other propeties has been migrated during transition from springboot 1.x to 2.x.

Comment: Yes . we have to check migration guide before migrating .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc)

> Spring Boot automatically creates the schema of an embedded
>   DataSource. This behaviour can be customized by using the
>   spring.datasource.initialization-mode property. For instance, if you
>   want to always initialize the DataSource regardless of its type:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Look at [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide)  migration guide

Answer (score 27):

In Spring Boot 2.5,  'spring.datasource.initialization-mode' has been depracated as well:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#SQL-Script-DataSource-Initialization

you should use:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

or

```
spring.sql.init.mode=never
```

You can read more at:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization

Comment: Thanks for the update. Shouldn't it be `spring.sql.init.mode=always` as per the official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts) though?

Comment: @dbaltor you are correct, it seems that they have changed the property again...

Answer (score 4):

The property `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` from Spring boot verion 2.7 and onwards is not any more depracated.  **It has been completely removed!**

So the change into the replacement property `spring.sql.init.mode` is a must do from now on.

[Spring Boot 2.7 changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7.0-Configuration-Changelog)

Answer (score 3):

As per Spring Boot Migration mentioned in [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide)

> Basic DataSource initialization is now only enabled for embedded data
>   sources and will switch off as soon as you’re using a production
>   database. The new spring.datasource.initialization-mode (replacing
>   spring.datasource.initialize) offers more control.

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization`. Refer to this Spring Documentation on how to  [Initialize a Database Using Basic SQL Scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts):

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

Answer (score 0):

spring.sql.init.enabled=true - to initialize database by data.sql script located in application resources
spring.sql.init.enabled=false - to